# Can the calender of a Silverlight DatePicker control be prevented from closing on date selection?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datepicker

[DatePicker MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

On selection of a date in the calendar (through clicking a CalendarDayButton) the calendar popup automatically closes. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour without editing the source of the control itself? (A ControlTemplate would be fine).

I am able to change the CalendarDayButton style & control template but I see nothing that would help me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you will have any luck changing this behaviour.  The code to cause the Datepicker to close appears to be here (I looked at the source of Datepicker from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80285#780085), Release -> Silverlight 4 -> Source -> Controls -> DatePicker)

```
private void Calendar_DayButtonMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
            this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
            _calendar.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
```

It is also closed here:

```
private void Calendar_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar c = sender as Calendar;
            Debug.Assert(c != null, "The Calendar should not be null!");

            if (!e.Handled && (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Escape) && c.DisplayMode == CalendarMode.Month)
            {
                this.Focus();
                this.IsDropDownOpen = false;

                if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
                {
                    this.SelectedDate = this._onOpenSelectedDate;
                }
            }
        }
```

Both of these handlers are added in a private method, `private void InitializeCalendar` , and the calender object itself is declared private (`private Calendar _calendar`).

Comment: I think you're right, even though it is not the answer I wanted to hear!